# Java library to read Windows Registry from Linux

Tags: java

Is there a Java library for reading the Windows Registry? I do not meaning calling Win32 APIs from Windows, but rather reading the file direct from Linux. The Windows drive is mounted on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no Java library for reading the Windows registry from Linux. The Windows registry is not stored as an ordinary file, and the CIFS (or SMB) file system does not expose the registry either.

Comment: If I was attaching to a live Windows system, your comment would be 100% correct. What I am trying to do is mount an offline drive into Linux and read the registry. There is a tool (http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) that can do it, but my preference is an embedded Java library... if such a beast exists.

Comment: I have seem them written in other languages as well, just oddly not Java. You may be correct in that it does not exist.